# Error Executing SQL file in Navicat

Tags: sql, navicat

I'm adding values into the table "traders_data", however when I execute the SQL I get the following error:

```
('["M1126_ICV_M2_EP1",2]', 1000, '[8,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',    '[3,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle'),
('["
[Msg] Finished - Unsuccessfully
```

I can't find any syntactical reason as to why this is happening. The full code is below, if anyone knows what is going on, I'd appreciate the help.

```
INSERT INTO `traders_data` (`item`,`qty`,`buy`,`sell`,`order`,`tid`,`afile`) VALUES
('["Ural_ZU23_CDF",2]', 1000, '[2,"ItemBriefcase100oz",1]', '[9,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle'),
('["M1126_ICV_M2_EP1",2]', 1000, '[8,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]', '[3,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle'),
('["M1126_ICV_mk19_EP1",2]', 1000, '[8,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]', '[3,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle'),
('["BAF_Jackal2_GMG_W",2]', 1000, '[6,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]', '[2,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle');
```

PS. I have very little experience with SQL so if I've screw up something  obvious, sorry in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes from **Table Name** and **Column Name**.

Add [ ] to **Order** column because it is's reserved word.

Remove "**,**" from the end of you sql.

```
INSERT INTO traders_data(item,qty,buy,sell,[order],tid,afile) 
VALUES
('["Ural_ZU23_CDF",2]', 1000, '[2,"ItemBriefcase100oz",1]','[9,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle')
,('["M1126_ICV_M2_EP1",2]', 1000, '[8,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]', '[3,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle')
,('["M1126_ICV_mk19_EP1",2]', 1000, '[8,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]', '[3,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle')
,('["BAF_Jackal2_GMG_W",2]', 1000, '[6,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]', '[2,"ItemGoldBar10oz",1]',0, 534, 'trade_any_vehicle');
```

Try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! They're actually backticks, which allows me to use `Order` for the column name...I think. The problem turned out to be, there were duplicate records, and for some reason Navicat couldn't handle that. I've removed those, and everything's working.